# How do I authenticate users with a site API?

Tags: php, api, oauth

I want to build an API for users to build applications that easily interact with a site, and I was wondering what the best way to authenticate users would be.

Taking a look at other API's a lot of them have the user send the username and password as a GET parameter over a HTTPS connection. Is this the best way to go about it? Or are there other methods that I should look into or consider?

I've seen OAuth been tossed around and it looks like a good solution, but just for a simple API is it overkill?

Comment: Are the current answers (un)satisfactory? It has been several months since you asked this question without any feedback from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API key's. Generate a unique hash tied to an account upon request. Then check that the key is a valid key. As long as the API doesn't have any major security issues with someone using someone else's key then Authorization isn't needed. If there is a problem with someone using someone else's key then Authentication would be justified.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually achieved with cookies.

The client sends their username and password with a **POST** request to your API (do *not* use GET, that's insecure). If the credentials are acceptable, then generate a random, unique session key, store it on your side and send it in a cookie back to the client (see [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)).

When the client now makes further requests, they send the session key cookie with the request. Check `$_COOKIE` for the session key if it matches a stored key on your side; if yes, that means the user authenticated.

Take note that this minimal example is vulnerable to brute-force attacks trying to guess valid session keys. You need to log invalid keys that clients send in their cookies and block their IP address for some period of time to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Username / password in a GET isn't a great way to do this because you're potentially exposing the whole user account for hijacking even if the API has more limited functionality than logging into the site. So it's good practice to separate concerns between Web-site login and API access.

I'm not sure which case you're in but:

- If the users are business customers of somekind who are embedding some type of widget or code in another website then it's probably best to use an API key which is scoped to the referrer domain (much like Google Maps does).
- If they are end-users who won't know anything about the API but are going to be using Apps built by third parties then oAuth is likely to be your best bet, otherwise your users might literally be giving their usernames/passwords to unknown third parties. It's more complex but likely to be worth it in the long run.

To get a bunch of this stuff out of the box you can use something like 3scale (http://www.3scale.net) and it'll handle most of it  for you (disclaimer, I work there so adjust for bias!) or there are open source libraries for oAuth in most languages (in PHP Zend-OAuth component might do the job for you).